# EStyleSheet Media queries and window resize

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-stylesheet, react-native-windows

I'm using React Native Extended StyleSheet to build a React Native app for WINDOWS.
When I use Media queries I get the query of the moment the app is launch, however I need It to be dynamic.
When I resize my app window I don't see my styles changing accordingly to the rules I have created. All the rules works, but none are fired by window resize.

Does anyone has a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

I recreate my eStylesheet when I detect the change. I don't think it does that automatically for you.